# PrimeFaces : Supporting which Web Browser & which OS platform

Tags: primefaces

I am very new in using Primefaces. I & our team planning to write Web Application that need to be running on Web Browser on both Windows OS and Mac OS . Here are my questions that need help for the answers :

(1) Can we develop  Web Application  be able to run on Web Browser on both Windows OS and Mac OS  ?
(2) What are Web Browsers on Windows OS that Primefaces support ? Which ones are the most compatible ?
(3) What are Web Browsers on Mac OS that Primefaces support ? Which ones are the most compatible ?

Thank you very much in advance.
Best Regards
Pearapon
Bangkok, Thailand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following: create a test primefaces application which contains all component that your application will use (even better if you test also nesting the components) with a mocked backend. Then test your test ui in all desired browsers on desired platforms but on differents OS it shouldn't be different. I only work with windows but I test the application on Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari and Opera. The only significant problems I faced was with CSS. E. g. a component does not use the full width etc.

Comment: I would not answer questions like this. They do not belong on SO and if 'we' do answer, people will keep asking them (and no the downvote is not mine, although I am kind of inclined to do so)

Comment: You can vote and downvote what you want. But why does the question not belong to SO ?